# VMware filed to install Windows Server 2008 in Windows 10 because winload.exe is missing or corrupt

Tags: windows-10, boot, vmware

I am trying to install Windows Server 2008 in VMware 12 in Windows 10 (64 bit), but VMware shows below error and failed to install.

File: \windows\system32\boot\winload.exe

status: 0X0000001

info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing and corrupt.

[image: VMware failed image]

- winload.exe is not missing but when I run it, "winload.exe application cannot be run in Win32 mode" appeared.
- I tried to fix and cleanup registry with CCleaner application, but it not worked.
- I tried to fix and repair MBR and BCD with Windows 10 CD, but it not worked too.

Windows 10 always boot without any problem. Is there any other solution?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my English.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying in the bullets.  How / where are you running ```winload.exe``` and CCleaner?  In your Windows 10 host?  That’s irrelevant to your VM.  Are you running them ***in*** the VM?  How, if you can’t install an operating system?

Comment: This is my first time using VMware. I did the solutions in hots OS (Windows 10).

Comment: I can't find any solution. I think the ISO file is corrupted. Thanks.

Comment: To a certain extent, you can think of a host and a VM/guest as two separate computers. Things that you do on one of them generally aren’t going to affect the other one very much. So verifying that `winload.exe` exists on the host doesn’t help you with the VM. Yes, a corrupted ISO could explain this.